# How to remove double quotes while assigning columns to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below list

```
ColumnName = 'Emp_id','Emp_Name','EmpAGe'
```

While i am trying to read above columns and assign inside dataframe i am getting extra double quotes

```
df = pd.dataframe(data,columns=[ColumnName])

columns=[ColumnName]

i am getting columns = ["'Emp_id','Emp_Name','EmpAGe'"]
```

how can i handle these extra double quotes and remove them while assigning header to data

Comment: I can't reproduce that

Comment: @U10-Forward . i didnt get

Comment: I just placed an example dataset , see if that helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you define the columns for pandas DataFrame.

The example below will build a correct data frame :

```
    import pandas as pd
    ColumnName1 = 'Emp_id','Emp_Name','EmpAGe'

    df1 = [['A1','A1','A2'],['1','2','1'],['a0','a1','a3']]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=df1,columns=ColumnName1 )

    df
```

Result :

```
    Emp_id  Emp_Name EmpAGe
0   A1      A1       A2
1   1       2        1
2   a0      a1      a3
```

A print screen of the code I wrote with the result, with no double quotations

[image]

Comment: @ J.K.. Thanks a lot for the reply.  I tried this but i am getting   ---- TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind,

Comment: @Arya, i edited my code and add the first line to include pandas. So if you copy/paste my code in Jupyter, it should work fine. If you still facing errors, please send me the exact error and what tool you are using.

Comment: @Arya, I edited my code and added a print-screen of the code with the result. I don't have any double quotations. If you copy the code, and still you see a double quotation, it may be related to the tool you are using, or something else...

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
ColumnName = 'Emp_id','Emp_Name','EmpAGe'
```

Is a tuple and not a list.
In case you want three columns, each with values on the tuple above you gonna need

```
df = pd.dataframe(data,columns=list(ColumnName))
```

Comment: @Thanks a lot for the reply , but columns are getting distributes like ['E','m','p'] ....

Comment: i am using same code as above but when i am trying to convert columns=list(ColumnName) or columns=eval(ColumnName) i am facing sometime issue as "TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind"

Comment: Maybe is the `data` variable you're using. Can you print it and show its format and values?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the shake of the understanding, where you can use `col.replace` to get the desired ..

Let take an example..

```
>>> df
   col1"  col2"
0      1      1
1      2      2
```

Result:

```
>>> df.columns = [col.replace('"', '') for col in df.columns]
  # df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('"', '')  <-- can use this as well
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     2     2
```

OR

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({ '"col1"':[1, 2], '"col2"':[1,2]})
>>> df
   "col1"  "col2"
0       1       1
1       2       2
>>> df.columns = [col.replace('"', '') for col in df.columns]
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not quite right. `ColumnName` is already list-like and it should be passed on directly rather than wrapped in another list. In the latter case it would be interpreted as one single column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=ColumnName)
```

Comment: @ I tried but still double quotes are getting added to leading and trailing ['Emp_id','Emp_Name','EmpAGe']"

Comment: @Arya, if you can put the real dataFrame example with the output  & error you are getting then better would be the answers. However, if you still getting quotes then you can try the answer i quoted just to double check.

Comment: @Arya Please provide [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for others to test.